# Prove: Let A be a finite set with at least 8 elements. Then A can be partitioned into subsets where each subset has size 3 or 5.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying proof this by induction.

Base Step I choose n=8,9,10
which When n=8 (3,5)  it's a combination of 3 and 5
When n=9 (3,3,3)It's just 3
When n=10 (5,5) it's only 5

In the induction step, I assume that Set A has K elements and Card(k)=3m+5n where m,n are integer.

I need to prove k+1 can be partition by 3 and 5.

Now I stuck at Card(k+1)=3m+5n+1.

Answer (score 2):

Prove it manually for $n \in \{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}.$

Then, if there is a partition for $n$, there must be one for $(n+8)$, because you can simply add one subset of size $3$ and one subset of size $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $P(k), P(k+1), P(k+2)$ is true, now we want to verify $P(k+3)$.

To partition $k+3$, we consider the partition that we can obtain from induction hypothesis $P(k)$ union it with the remaining set of size $3$.

Comment: +1 : embarrassing how much better your answer is than mine.

Comment: your answer tells us how to obtain non-unique partition. :)

Comment: please explain, what is the difference between a unique and non-unique partition?  I would imagine that for any value of $n \geq (8 + 15)$ no partitions are unique, since you can add either $3$ subsets of size 5 or $5$ subsets of size 3 to the partitioning of $(n-15).$

Comment: it's what you stated. Example:  $15$ can be written as the sum of three $5$'s and also sum of five $3$'s.  mine approach just keep adding set of size $3$ to the previous construct though it serves the purpose of answering the question.

Comment: i regard your answer as better, because you don't have to manually check $\{11,12,13,14,15\}.$